# Select cells in Excel based on cell content

Tags: vba, excel, toad

I'm working with Excel trying to write a macro in VB for Applications and could use your help.

**My Goal:**

Export 1000s of records from Toad to Excel, and then run a macro that will place certain records on certain sheets based on cell content.

**Example of my data:**

[image]

(Sorry, I'd post the image inline, but I don't have enough reputation)

**Explanation of data:**

Privilege - The different roles of users
User_name - The user name of each user
Sort_name - last_name, first_name of each user

**What I'd like the macro to do:**

In the privilege column, select all records with the same priv and their corresponding details, cut them, and paste them on a new sheet. Repeat this for privilege through the end of the data.

**Example:**

Select all Admin rows along with user_name and sort_name. Cut selected rows, paste on sheet2.
Select all Moderator rows along with user_name and sort_name. Cut selected rows, paste on sheet3.
Select all GeneralUser rows along with user_name and sort_name. Cut selected rows, paste on sheet4.

**Additional info:**

In my actual data, there are thousands of rows with about 60 different privileges. So, when I run this on my real data, it will result in a workbook with 60 different sheets.

Privileges will be in order. All Admins will be together. There won't be 10 Admin's from cell A2-A9 and then more from A67-A100. They're sequential.

The first sheet with the raw data in it is going to be deleted at the end of this process, so it's formatting does not matter.

**I've tried:**

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'

'
    Range("A2:C9").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A10:C14").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A15:C25").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

But that selects generic cells, not cells based on the text written. This means it's not coded for variable length.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Well, that's my issue. I haven't done a lot with Excel macros, so I don't know what to try. I was hoping that someone could recommend some methods. I've tried using Range.Find, but that doesn't seem to select the cells. See my edit.

Comment: The macro recorder is normally a good start if you dont know where to begin

Comment: My edit is on the original question now. Sorry that took me a minute. I wanted to make it look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, below assumes: sheets are not created for privs, data is sorted by column A, the activesheet is the sheet with your data

Values_To_Find will need to be changed to all the privs you have, it is just a comma seperated list

It does not delete the original sheet

```
Sub t()
Dim start_rng As Range

Values_To_Find = "Admin,Moderator,GeneralUser"
sp = Split(Values_To_Find, ",")

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 0 To UBound(sp)
        Found = 0
        Set start_rng = .Range("A1")
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:" & .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Address)
            If Found = 1 And cell.Value <> sp(i) Then 'find end
                Set end_rng = cell
                Exit For
            End If
            If cell.Value = sp(i) And start_rng.Address = "$A$1" Then 'find start
                Set start_rng = cell
                Found = 1
            End If
        Next

        Set ws = Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = sp(i)
        .Range(start_rng.Address & ":" & Range(end_rng.Address).Offset(-1, 3).Address).Copy
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think I'll need to tweak this some, I'm getting a weird error, and the output isn't right, but it's closer than I was before. Thank you very much for your help, and time.